# ReactJS: material-ui error when import Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying my app using `material-ui` lib.

I create a `Table` and just follow the code in [Custom Table Pagination Action](https://material-ui.com/demos/tables/), but I got the error like this.

Error I got:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `TablePaginationActions`.
    in TablePaginationActions (created by WithStyles(TablePaginationActions))
    in WithStyles(TablePaginationActions) (created by TablePagination)
```

My `DataTables` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {
  ListItem,
  TableFooter,
  TablePagination,
  ListItemText,
  Avatar,
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  Paper
} from '@material-ui/core';

import TablePaginationActionsWrapped from './TablePaginationActions'

const CustomTableCell = withStyles(theme => ({
  body: {
    fontSize: 14,
    paddingRight: 0,
  },
  head: {
    paddingRight: 0,
  }
}))(TableCell);

const CustomTableRow = withStyles(theme => ({
  root: {},
}))(TableRow);

const CustomTableHead = withStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    padding: '0'
  },
}))(TableHead);

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    overflowX: 'auto',
    borderRadius: '0'
  },
  table: {
    minWidth: 500,
  },
  tableWrapper: {
    overflowX: 'auto',
  },
});

class DataTables extends Component {

  state = {
    data: this.props.reportsList,
    page: 0,
    rowsPerPage: 10,
  }

  handleChangePage = (event, page) => {
    this.setState({page});
  };

  handleChangeRowsPerPage = event => {
    this.setState({rowsPerPage: event.target.value});
  };

  render() {
    const {classes, reportsList} = this.props;
    const {data, rowsPerPage, page} = this.state;
    const emptyRows = rowsPerPage - Math.min(rowsPerPage, data.length - page * rowsPerPage);

    return (
      <Paper className={classes.root}>
        <div className={classes.tableWrapper}>
          <Table className={classes.table}>
            <CustomTableHead>
              <CustomTableRow>
                <CustomTableCell>ID</CustomTableCell>
                <CustomTableCell>Report Title</CustomTableCell>
                <CustomTableCell>Author</CustomTableCell>
                <CustomTableCell>Date created</CustomTableCell>
              </CustomTableRow>
            </CustomTableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {data.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage).map(report => {
                return (
                  <CustomTableRow key={report.id}>
                    <CustomTableCell>{report.id}</CustomTableCell>
                    <CustomTableCell component="th" scope="row">
                      {report.title}
                    </CustomTableCell>
                    <CustomTableCell padding="none" component="th" scope="row">
                      <ListItem>
                        <Avatar alt="Avatar image" src={report.userId.avatar}/>
                        <ListItemText>{report.userId.firstName}</ListItemText>
                      </ListItem>
                    </CustomTableCell>
                    <CustomTableCell component="th" scope="row">
                      {report.date}
                    </CustomTableCell>
                  </CustomTableRow>
                );
              })}
              {emptyRows > 0 && (
                <TableRow style={{ height: 48 * emptyRows }}>
                  <TableCell colSpan={6} />
                </TableRow>
              )}
            </TableBody>
            <TableFooter>
              <TableRow>
                <TablePagination
                  colSpan={3}
                  count={reportsList.length}
                  rowsPerPage={this.state.rowsPerPage}
                  page={this.state.page}
                  onChangePage={this.handleChangePage}
                  onChangeRowsPerPage={this.handleChangeRowsPerPage}
                  ActionsComponent={TablePaginationActionsWrapped}

                  // ActionsComponent={TablePaginationActionsWrapped} If not use this, my app work fine.
                />
              </TableRow>
            </TableFooter>
          </Table>
        </div>
      </Paper>
    );
  }
}

DataTables.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(DataTables);
```

And my `TablePaginationActionsWrapped` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import { FirstPageIcon, KeyboardArrowLeft, KeyboardArrowRight, LastPageIcon } from '@material-ui/icons'

const actionsStyles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexShrink: 0,
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit * 2.5,
  },
});

class TablePaginationActions extends Component {

  handleFirstPageButtonClick = event => {
    this.props.onChangePage(event, 0);
  };

  handleBackButtonClick = event => {
    this.props.onChangePage(event, this.props.page - 1);
  };

  handleNextButtonClick = event => {
    this.props.onChangePage(event, this.props.page + 1);
  };

  handleLastPageButtonClick = event => {
    this.props.onChangePage(
      event,
      Math.max(0, Math.ceil(this.props.count / this.props.rowsPerPage) - 1),
    );
  };

  render() {

    const { classes, count, page, rowsPerPage, theme } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <IconButton
          onClick={this.handleFirstPageButtonClick}
          disabled={page === 0}
          aria-label="First Page"
        >
          {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <LastPageIcon /> : <FirstPageIcon />}
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton
          onClick={this.handleBackButtonClick}
          disabled={page === 0}
          aria-label="Previous Page"
        >
          {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <KeyboardArrowRight /> : <KeyboardArrowLeft />}
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton
          onClick={this.handleNextButtonClick}
          disabled={page >= Math.ceil(count / rowsPerPage) - 1}
          aria-label="Next Page"
        >
          {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <KeyboardArrowLeft /> : <KeyboardArrowRight />}
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton
          onClick={this.handleLastPageButtonClick}
          disabled={page >= Math.ceil(count / rowsPerPage) - 1}
          aria-label="Last Page"
        >
          {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <FirstPageIcon /> : <LastPageIcon />}
        </IconButton>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

TablePaginationActions.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  count: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  onChangePage: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  page: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  rowsPerPage: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  theme: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const TablePaginationActionsWrapped = withStyles(actionsStyles, { withTheme: true })(
  TablePaginationActions,
);

export default TablePaginationActionsWrapped;
```

What did I'm wrong here. please help me.

Comment: You put "import TablePaginationActionsWrapped from './TablePaginationActions'**" and in your comments you said that the file name ends with **wrapper**.  What is the right filename. You must have this name in the import default wrapper from '. /rightFileName'

Comment: Sorry about the format.  I did the comment from the phone and I did something wrong .

Comment: @AntonioRodriguez you mean `import TablePaginationActionsWrapped from './TablePaginationActions'` the name and the url should be the same ?

Comment: Try `console.log(classes)` or other variable in your `render()` method. I saw you destructuring classes from props but I didn't see it set anywhere.

Comment: Not necessarily. Maybe I get confused.  I will take a look more deeply.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one issue. You are using wrong name for icon components. It is `LastPage` and `FirstPage` not `LastPageIcon` and `FirstPageIcon`. Just correct it, and it will work fine.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton'
import { FirstPage, KeyboardArrowLeft, KeyboardArrowRight, LastPage } from '@material-ui/icons'

const actionsStyles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexShrink: 0,
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit * 2.5
  }
})

class TablePaginationActions extends Component {
  handleFirstPageButtonClick = event => {
    this
      .props
      .onChangePage(event, 0)
  }

  handleBackButtonClick = event => {
    this
      .props
      .onChangePage(event, this.props.page - 1)
  }

  handleNextButtonClick = event => {
    this
      .props
      .onChangePage(event, this.props.page + 1)
  }

  handleLastPageButtonClick = event => {
    this
      .props
      .onChangePage(event, Math.max(0, Math.ceil(this.props.count / this.props.rowsPerPage) - 1))
  }

  render() {
    const { classes, count, page, rowsPerPage, theme } = this.props

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <IconButton
          onClick={this.handleFirstPageButtonClick}
          disabled={page === 0}
          aria-label='First Page'>
          {theme.direction === 'rtl'
            ? <LastPage/>
            : <FirstPage />}
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton
          onClick={this.handleBackButtonClick}
          disabled={page === 0}
          aria-label='Previous Page'>
          {theme.direction === 'rtl'
            ? <KeyboardArrowRight />
            : <KeyboardArrowLeft />}
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton
          onClick={this.handleNextButtonClick}
          disabled={page >= Math.ceil(count / rowsPerPage) - 1}
          aria-label='Next Page'>
          {theme.direction === 'rtl'
            ? <KeyboardArrowLeft />
            : <KeyboardArrowRight />}
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton
          onClick={this.handleLastPageButtonClick}
          disabled={page >= Math.ceil(count / rowsPerPage) - 1}
          aria-label='Last Page' />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

TablePaginationActions.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  count: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  onChangePage: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  page: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  rowsPerPage: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  theme: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default withStyles(actionsStyles, { withTheme: true })(TablePaginationActions)
```

Try replacing, it should work. You can check icon name from https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=first_page&style=baseline. You just need to use it by converting it to Capital case. Like icon `first_page` becomes `FirstPage` in `@material-ui/icons`.